# How many ways are there to add up odd integers to 20?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to add up odd integers to 20?

Here, $1+19$ is one solution, $19+1$ is a different solution, and $1+1+\dots+1$ counts as just one solution.

Comment: Probably you mean odd positive integers. If it is two positive integers, make a list and count. If we allow things like $3+1+5+1+1+9$, some general theory is useful, since the number of possibilities is large.

Comment: Question (a) Two odd integers (b) general case of any number of odd integers,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To sum up to $20$, we could:

- first write a $1$ and **count all the ways to add up to the remainder, $19$**, or
- first write a $3$ and **count all the ways to add up to the remainder, $17$**, or
- first write a $5$ and **count all the ways to add up to the remainder, $15$**, or …

The answer will be the sum of all these counts.

---

Let’s denote the number of lists of odd positive integers that sum to $n$ as $a_n$.

We can easily see that $a_1 = 1$ (just $1$) and $a_2 = 1$ (just $1+1$).

We can generalize our observation and say that, for $n \geq 1$,
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-3} + a_{n-5} + \dots \tag{i}$$
ending at either $a_1$ (if $n$ is even) or $a_0$ (if $n$ is odd).

But then also for $n \geq 3$,
$$ a_{n-2} = a_{n-3} + a_{n-5} + \dots \tag{ii}$$
so combining $\text{(i)}$ and $\text{(ii)}$ we find
$$ a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}, $$
meaning $a_n$ are just the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) ($1, 1, 2, 3, 5, \dots$).

Thus $a_{20}$ is the twentieth Fibonacci number, $6765$.

Answer (score 0):

Length[Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[20, All, 2 Range[10] - 1], 1]]

6765 ways, according to Mathematica.